# Java test for MD5 using a file

Tags: java, user-interface, md5

I have two java programs one, a gui that opens a text file. And one that encrypts data using MD5. How can I combine the two so my gui will display the text in the file and the encrypted version of the text.

GUI

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Editor extends JFrame implements WindowListener, ActionListener {

JTextField fileName;
JTextArea fileBuffer;
JButton load, save, quit;   

/** Creates a new instance of Editor */
public Editor() {

this.setLayout(null);
//      this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

JLabel label=new JLabel("File Name: ");
label.setBounds(10,30,300,20);
label.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
this.add(label);

fileName=new JTextField();
fileName.setBounds(10,50,290,20);
this.add(fileName);

load=new JButton("Load");
load.setBounds(10,80,80,20);
this.add(load);

save=new JButton("Save");
save.setBounds(110,80,80,20);
this.add(save);

quit=new JButton("Quit");
quit.setBounds(210,80,80,20);
this.add(quit);



 fileBuffer=new JTextArea("",10,20);
 JScrollPane p=new JScrollPane(fileBuffer);

 JPanel panel=new JPanel();
//     panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
 panel.add(p);
 panel.setBounds(15, 110,275,210);


 this.getContentPane().add(panel);



this.addWindowListener(this);
load.addActionListener(this);
save.addActionListener(this);
quit.addActionListener(this);

}//Constructor Editor


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
  String command=e.getActionCommand();
  if (command.equals("Quit")) dispose();
  else if (command.equals("Load")) load();
  else if (command.equals("Save")) save();     
}

public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){dispose();}
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e){}
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e){}
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e){}
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e){}
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e){}
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e){}


void load(){
    try{
        RandomAccessFile input=new  RandomAccessFile(fileName.getText() ,"r");
        byte buffer[]=new byte [(int) input.length()];
        input.read(buffer);
        input.close();
        fileBuffer.setText(new String(buffer));           
    }
    catch(IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}

}

void save(){
    try{
        FileWriter output= new FileWriter(fileName.getText());
        output.write(fileBuffer.getText());
        output.close();           
    }
    catch(IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}

}


public static void main(String [] args){
   Editor edit=new Editor();
   edit.setSize(320,320);
   edit.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
   edit.setTitle("Editor de Texto SWING");
   edit.setVisible(true);       
}  
}
```

MD5 Program:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class TestMD5
{
private static final char[] CONSTS_HEX = {    '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f' };
public static String encryptionMD5(String token)
{
    try
    {
       MessageDigest msgd = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
       byte[] bytes = msgd.digest(token.getBytes());
       StringBuilder strbMD5 = new StringBuilder(2 * bytes.length);
       for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
       {
           int low = (int)(bytes[i] & 0x0f);
           int high = (int)((bytes[i] & 0xf0) >> 4);
           strbMD5.append(CONSTS_HEX[high]);
           strbMD5.append(CONSTS_HEX[low]);
       }
       return strbMD5.toString();
    }catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
             return null;
     }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    String msg01=new String("12345678910");
     String msg02=new String("12345678910 ");
    System.out.println("\n\nMD5 Encryption of" +msg01+": "+encryptionMD5(msg01));
    System.out.println("MD5 Encryption of "+msg02+":"+encryptionMD5(msg02));
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `new TextArea say encryptedBuffer` to a `new Scroll Pane` and add it to your jPanel and modify your load method like this:

```
void load(){
    try{
        RandomAccessFile input=new  RandomAccessFile(fileName.getText() ,"r");
        byte buffer[]=new byte [(int) input.length()];
        input.read(buffer);
        input.close();
        String content = new String(buffer);
        fileBuffer.setText(content); 
        encryptedBuffer.setText(TestMD5.encryptionMD5(content));        
    }
    catch(IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion worked

Comment: @Jessica Your welcome. Have fun coding :)

Answer (score 1):

- Encrypt the plain file, saving it's contents to a second file
- Create two `JTextArea`'s and use the [`JTextArea#read(Reader, Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29) method to read the two files...

Swing applications are intended to be platform independent, on of the most significant issues is supporting platform rendering differences, including font differences and DPI to mention a couple.

Swing utilises the layout manager functionality to reduce this complexity which allows to focus more on usability and work flow rather than trying to calculate the difference between components because of differences with the way the output is rendered.

**Updated with example**

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Crypto {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Crypto();
    }

    public Crypto() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy = 0;
                gbc.weighty = 1;
                gbc.weightx = 1;
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

                final FilePane sourcePane = new FilePane(true);
                final FilePane encryptPane = new FilePane(false);

                frame.add(sourcePane, gbc);
                gbc.gridx = 2;
                frame.add(encryptPane, gbc);

                JButton encrypt = new JButton("Encrypt >>");
                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                panel.add(encrypt);

                encrypt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        File source = sourcePane.getFile();
                        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(source))) {
                            char[] buffer = new char[1024];
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
                            int bytesRead = -1;
                            while ((bytesRead = br.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                sb.append(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            }
                            String encrypted = encryptionMD5(sb.toString());

                            File enrypt = new File(source.getPath() + ".enrypted");
                            try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(enrypt))) {
                                bw.write(encrypted);
                            } catch (Exception exp) {
                                exp.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            encryptPane.setFile(enrypt);

                        } catch (Exception exp) {
                            exp.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                gbc.gridx = 1;
                gbc.weighty = 1;
                gbc.weightx = 0;
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
                frame.add(panel, gbc);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static String encryptionMD5(String token) {
        char[] hex = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
        try {
            MessageDigest msgd = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            byte[] bytes = msgd.digest(token.getBytes());
            StringBuilder strbMD5 = new StringBuilder(2 * bytes.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                int low = (int) (bytes[i] & 0x0f);
                int high = (int) ((bytes[i] & 0xf0) >> 4);
                strbMD5.append(hex[high]);
                strbMD5.append(hex[low]);
            }
            return strbMD5.toString();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class FilePane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField field;
        private JButton browse;
        private JTextArea content;

        private File file;

        public FilePane(boolean canOpen) {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            field = new JTextField();
            field.setEditable(false);

            content = new JTextArea(20, 20);
//            content.setLineWrap(true);
//            content.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            content.setEditable(false);

            add(new JScrollPane(content));

            JPanel header = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            header.add(field, gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.weightx = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            if (canOpen) {
                browse = new JButton("...");
                browse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
                        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
                        switch (chooser.showOpenDialog(FilePane.this)) {
                            case JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION:
                                setFile(chooser.getSelectedFile());
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
                header.add(browse, gbc);
            }

            add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        }

        public File getFile() {
            return file;
        }

        public void setFile(File f) {
            file = f;
            field.setText(file.getPath());
            if (file != null) {
                try (Reader r = new FileReader(file)) {
                    content.read(r, file);
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                }
            } else {
                content.setText(null);
            }
            content.setCaretPosition(0);
        }

    }

}
```

ps- Instead of copying the MD5 calculation directly as I did, you could just call `TestMD5.encryptionMD5` as it's a `static` method

Answer (score 0):

Just create a second `JTextArea`, and set its text to `TestMD5.encryptionMD5(`*whatever* `)`